# HTML & CSS: My UL extends out of container

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with my UL. I set its width:100%, but it looks like to extend outside the container.

Here's the link to the picture:
http://s10.postimg.org/kp3i5v4mh/websiteuloutofcontainer.png

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <title>Official Website of Andrew</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css" />
<head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<header>
<img id="andrewvuheader" src="images/andrewheader.png" alt="andrewvuheader" />

<div id="break"></div>

<ul>
   <li><a href="#" target="_blank">HOME</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" target="_blank">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" target="_blank">PROJECTS</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" target="_blank">COLLABORATE</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" target="_blank">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</header>


</div> <!-- container DIV -->

</body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
html, body  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

/***************************
******* CONTAINER **********
***************************/

#container  {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 1080px;
    max-width: 90%;
}

/***************************
********** HEADER **********
***************************/

header  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid green;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 99.6%;
    height: 139px;
}

/* Andrew Vu Header */
img #anderwvuheader  {
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

/* Clears all float properties */
#break  {
    clear: both;
}

/***** Menu *****/
header ul  {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 20px 35px 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: -5px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -1.8px;
    min-width: 500px;
}

/***** Listed Items *****/
header ul li {
    background-color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

header ul li a  {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Normal, unvisited link */
header ul li a:link  {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* Visited link */
header ul li a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* Mouse over link */
header ul li a:hover {
    color: yellow;
}

/* Selected link */
header ul li a:active {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: use `box-sizing:border-box` for `header ul li` it will fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

I think that's happening because of padding property set up for your ul and li elements. Keep in mind that padding will increase size of block independently of which width or height you'd set.

You can remove width property from ul styles and check it out.

Comment: I removed width property from UL. Now, it looks like its width isn't touching at the end of the container (on the right)?

Comment: Right. Look at min-width property you've set for ul block - it's 500px. You have to add ul padding (right/left) value to this 500 and then add horizontal padding of each li element inside ul to get amount width.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the padding-left and padding-right from the ul. Or as in your example set the padding of the ul to: `20px 0px 35px 0px`=> `top-right-down-left` padding;

Also, remove the  `margin-left: -1.8px;`.

CSS:

```
header ul  {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 0px 35px 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: -5px;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/94kuncnj/1/).

Comment: Thanks for that. But I still see that it still extends out of the container?

Comment: Because you have a `margin-left: -1.8px;` on the ul, remove it.

Comment: OK, removed the margin-left: -1.8px. Now, both sides looks like it's not really flushed to both left and right side of container?..

Comment: Edit: I removed the green border around the Header, and now the UL is flushed to the left side of the container. However, the right isn't flushed to the right side of the container.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because you have right/left padding applied to your UL.
Using both `padding` and `width:100%;`will cause the length of the element to be `100% + rigt/left padding`in width.

What you can do is add [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) to your `UL` element. When you use box-sizing, your padding/borders etc will not change the width of your element but will instead be applied *within* it.

```
header ul  {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 20px 35px 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: -5px;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 500px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aj0ptk48/1/)